# Invoke method when slider maxValue changed in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity slider has a callback called onValueChanged that I can add a listener to, but there's no "onMaxValueChanged" event, I wanna invoke a method when a slider's maxValue changed, is there any graceful way to do it?

Comment: At the place where you change the max value in your code invoke an event?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //A place to store it
    float currentMaxV;
    //Set it
    currentMaxV = sliderX.maxValue;
    //Detect it
    if(sliderX.maxValue > currentMaxV)
    {
        //Slider max value changed
        currentMaxV = sliderX.maxValue;
    }
```

That's the simple way - Or you could build your own slider - Or alter the slider script to include a getter and a setter and then add an event handler to that getter/setter.

This may help [Variable Listener](https://forum.unity.com/threads/variable-listener.468721/)